# Failover stopped - not sure how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I noticed my SQL failover instance stopped syncing with the master.  The master is running Ok - but am not sure how to get the failover going again.

I tried deleting the failover and recreating it - it gets to a certain point and fails with:

```
[ERROR] Slave SQL: Could not execute Delete_rows event on table xxxx-wp.xh77t_options; Can't find record in 'xh77t_options', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log mysql-bin.008554, end_log_pos 58048670, Error_code: 1032
[Warning] Slave: Can't find record in 'xh77t_options' Error_code: 1032"  
 timestamp:  "2019-02-25T15:26:57.508699Z"
```

The database record xxxx-wp-xh77t seems Ok.

How do I fix this?  And is there a way to reset the syncronization without recreating the failover?

Comment: Sorry, are you using MySQL, or SQL, and, if you are using Cloud MySQL, I guess you are using 2nd gen?

Comment: Yes, Cloud MySql 2nd Gen